# How to prevent of selecting another row in TableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-8

Suppose, I would like to implement data validation in JavaFX TableView.

Once user have changed data in the row, I would like to check it when user is trying to change current row number. Once data is correct, I would like to allow row change, once data is incorrect, I want to disallow this.

How to implement this?

Currently, I am trying to add a listener

```
getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(indexFromTableToModel);
```

but any operations inside it causes bad table view behavior. Using

```
Platform.runLater
```

makes situation better, but still imperfect.

Is there a convenient place, to perform row data validation and perform different operation depending on it?

Comment: Not sure if exact answer can be given without knowing what you are changing in your listener, but I find that sometimes adding `TableView#layout` before changing selected index fixes graphical glitches (one row appears selected while another is actually being changed, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own selection model that can be locked (if current value is invalid). In that case the model won't change the internal selected index.